# Why this regex doesn't work in my vb.net code?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have some strange issue to deal with. I used this site https://regex101.com/ to test my result string.
I need to get visitors user-agent string where they visiting my site and then I create small app to get this done to my vb.net code.

The html code where it grab is this:

```
<body>
<p id="ip">ip: 77.111.247.210</p>
<p id="host">host: 77.111.247.210.dynamic.orange.fr</p>
<p id="port">port: 18516</p>
<p id="ua">ua: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36</p>
<p id="lang">lang: en-US,en;q=0.9</p>
<p id="mime">mime: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3</p>
<p id="encoding">encoding: gzip, deflate</p>
```

The pattern I use is this:`(?<=ua:)([^0-9a-zA-Z].+)(?=<)`
It works in regex tester website but in my vb.net code I tried and it not return anything.

```
 Dim r3 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=ua:)([^0-9a-zA-Z].+)(?=<)")
 Dim m3 = r3.Match(source)
 _ua = m3.Value
```

I can extract all parameters but the useragent 'ua:' it is impossible.
I just edited this and I have tested to ADD to my WebRequest `useragent` but I typed:  `the_request.UserAgent = "default"` and guess what..? It works BUT then I extracted not the correct useragent but the request useragent "default" lol how to fix it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your code works, [see demo](https://ideone.com/gpGyA2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i know but in vb.net desktop app it doesnt so i need to know why I can extract all from body and useragent it can not be done that the issue

Comment: So it is up to you to post a reproducible example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is there the vb.net code I used to gram IP, Port, Hostname ...but useragent is blank even the regex is correct, why?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have EDITED my question pls read the last words it is strange what I found.

Comment: It works and returns _Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36_ ! If you need _ua: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36_ then use `(ua:[^0-9a-zA-Z].+(?=<))` pattern instead. Still no? then please edit your post and past the content of the `source` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that to check useragent with webrequest it is not possible unless we do not use in request itself useragent. So thats why I did not get any string as I used request without useragent.